# К добавить цвета в exe в auto-py-to-exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, auto-py-to-exe

Часть кода:
\033[1;34mOS:\033[0m \033[1;33m{ os_name}\033[0

Это "\033[1;34\033[0m" отвечает за цвет, в консоли Vs кода цвета отображаются, а при конвертировании в exe в cmd цвета не отображаются

Comment: это называется ANSI-код и я все еще не нашел как исправить то что он не отображается нормально при конвертировании в exe

Comment: Это вообще не связано с auto-py-to-exe, это в принципе из коробки не поддерживается стандартным терминалом windows. Чтобы работало под windows, нужен, например, модуль colorama, его импортировать и инициализировать.

Answer (score 0):

Консоль (кажется, у Вас windows) тоже программа. И насколько она обрабатывает цвета (цвета см. https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/158854/) зависит от возможностей программы. Вот варианты воспроизведения такого вот кода, сконвертированного в exe:

```
print("\033[3m\033[33m\033[41m{}\033[0m".format("Htua_0111100000"))
```

Стандартная консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль FAR manager:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Консоль WindowsTerminal:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что там за консоль у Vs, и что это за Vs вообще :), не знаю. В FAR можно настроить запуск его консоли вместо стандартной. В WindowsTerminal не смотрел.